# How do I read text from .txt file into an array?

Tags: c++, file, text

I want to open a text file and read it in its entirety while storing its contents into variables and arrays using c++. I have my example text file below.  I would like to store the first line into an integer variable, the second line into a 3d array index and the final line into 5 elements of a string array.I know how to open the file for reading but I haven't learned how to read certain words and store them as integer or string types. I am not sure how to accomplish this in c++, any help is greatly appreciated.

```
3
2 3 3
4567 2939 2992 2222 0000
```

Comment: Too many questions like this.  Search the internet for "stackoverflow c++ read file array".

Answer (score 4):

Reading all the ints in a text file:

```
#include <fstream>

int main() {
    std::ifstream in;
    in.open("input_file.txt")
    // Fixed size array used to store the elements in the text file.
    // Change array type according to the type of the elements you want to read from the file
    int v[5];
    int element;

    if (in.is_open()) {
        int i = 0;
        while (in >> element) {
            v[i++] = element;
        }
    }

    in.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Include the `fstream`:

```cpp
#include <fstream>
```

And use `ifstream`:

```cpp
std::ifstream input( "filename.txt" );
```

To be able to read line by line:

```cpp
for( std::string line; std::getline( input, line ); )
{
    //do what you want for each line input here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream file("filename.txt"); // enter the name of your file here

    int firstLine;

    int secondLine;
    const int X = 3;
    const int Y = 1;
    const int Z = 1;
    int ***arr3D;

    std::string myArray[5];
    std::string myString;

    if (file.is_open())
    {
        // store the first line into an integer variable
        file >> firstLine;

        // store the second line into a 3d array index
        arr3D = new int**[X];
        for (int i = 0; i < X; i++)
        {
            arr3D[i] = new int*[Y];

            for (int j = 0; j < Y; j++)
            {
                arr3D[i][j] = new int[Z];

                for (int k = 0; k < Z; k++)
                {
                    file >> secondLine;
                    arr3D[i][j][k] = secondLine;
                }
            }
        }

        // store the final line into 5 elements of a string array
        int i = 0;
        while (file >> myString)
        {
            myArray[i] = myString;
            i++;
        }
    }

    file.close();


    std::cout << firstLine << std::endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < X; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < Y; j++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < Z; k++)
            {
                std::cout << arr3D[i][j][k] << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        std::cout << myArray[i] << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I rejected [one of your edits](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14444577), and you had a similar one rejected recently. Please don't edit the code of others in questions! You can never know whether your specific edit accidentally solves the original problem of the asker. Stick to formatting and grammar and tags, if anything. (I wrote as much in the rejection reason for your edit, but I wasn't sure you'd read it.) Thank you.